# preg_match a number in a comma-delimited string

Tags: php, regex

Is there a more elegant way to write the regex for a preg_match that finds a number in a comma-delimited string?

YES = 3 or ,3 or 3, or ,3,  (although 3 without a comma on either side will probably never happen)

NO = 13 or 13, or ,13 or ,13,

Here is what I wrote and it seems to work...

```
preg_match("/(,3,|,3(?!\d)|(?<!\d)3\,)/", $_SESSION['field_list'])
```

Comment: or `/.*?([0-9]+).*?/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a more general pattern:

```
$pattern = '~(?<=^|\D)3(?=\D|$)~';
```

Testing the comma presence seems in fine not very useful since you allow all that is not a number in your example pattern.

You can be more restrictive allowing only white characters or comma:

```
$pattern = '~(?<=^|\s|,)3(?=\s|,|$)~';
```

Notice: if it is only for testing, you can replace lookarounds by non capturing groups:

```
$pattern = '~(?:^|\D)3(?:\D|$)~';
```

or

```
$pattern = '~(?:^|\s|,)3(?:\s|,|$)~';
```

Answer (score 0):

try my solution on [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/)

`/.*?([0-9]+).*?/ims`

tested with: `2,123,4,5 4 or 5 x = 6 / 8`

it will work on any string

Answer (score 0):

I'd question whether regex is the right tool for this job.

Why don't you split the string first. Use [`str_getcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to turn it into an array.

Then you can simply look at each element to check for it being numeric. Or check for the specific numeric values you're after. No regex required.

Comment: thought about it, but i opted to just compare the checkbox row against the whole string to decide whether to check it or not